# ElasticSearch with Nest: Partial search using multiple words using Query<>.Wildcard

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-net

I have been pulling my hair out trying to configure and partial search ElasticSearch indexed data using Nest library version 5.3.1 (same version applies to its one of its dependencies; Elasticsearch.Net).

As per suggestions found online I used data attributes to specify analyzer type on some of the indexed properties as shown below:

```
public class Article
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Completion(Analyzer = "standard", PreservePositionIncrements = true, PreserveSeparators = true)]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
    }
```

I have at least one record in the search index for type "Article" having title starting with "The greatest ....". Whenever I perform a partial search for a keyword "greatest" using code below, it works just fine returning matching search results.

```
MultiTermQueryRewrite multiqueryRewrite = null;
var searchQuery = Query<Article>.Wildcard(f => f.Title, "*greatest*", rewrite: multiqueryRewrite);

var client = ElasticsearchClient.GetClient<Article>();
return client.Search<Article>(s => s.Query(searchQuery));
```

But... if I try searching for "the greatest" keywords with any variation listed below, I don't get any results back.

```
var searchQuery = Query<Article>.Wildcard(f => f.Title, "*the greatest*", rewrite: multiqueryRewrite);
```

or

```
var searchQuery = Query<Article>.Wildcard(f => f.Title, "*the*greatest*", rewrite: multiqueryRewrite);
```

or even

```
var searchQuery = Query<Article>.Wildcard(f => f.Title, "*the?greatest*", rewrite: multiqueryRewrite);
```

I am new to the ElasticSearch product, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per documentation

> Wild card Matches documents that have fields matching a wildcard expression (**not analyzed**).

Since title field is `Analyzed`, it gets tokenized before getting indexed. Some text say `The Greatest` will get tokenized and then converted into lower case (**Behaviour Of Standard Analyzer**). So it will be stored in reverse index as two tokens `the` and `greatest`.

When you search for `*greatest*`. It is searched as there is a token corresponding to that.

But when you search for `* the greatest *` , it is not found as there is no token which contains this text.

You can use [Query String](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/query-string-usage.html)

```
 var searchQuery = Query<Article>.QueryString(c => c
.Query("*the greatest*")
.DefaultField(p=>p.Title))
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Richa, I did find it very useful. Based on your suggestion I ended up having to additionally specify the "Default Operator" just to ensure both "the" and "greatest" words ae present in the matched results. `Query<Article>.QueryString(qs => qs.Query(term).DefaultField(f => f.Title).DefaultOperator(Operator.And));`

Answer (score 0):

The standard analyzer applied to the Title field produces lower case terms of your "The Greatest" Title in the following format [the, greatest]. You could consider using the [Keyword Analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-keyword-analyzer.html) but please note you will have to deal with word casing.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion @JoanieBrar